# HiveDB in macos build flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I have a flutter app that uses hiveDB, its working perfectly on iOS device and simulator, but when building it on macOS, the following error pops.

```
Unhandled Exception: HiveError: Cannot read, unknown typeId: 32. Did you forget to register an adapter?
```

This is my main method:

```
main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  Hive.registerAdapter(PriceAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter(AmountAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter(CustomerAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter(ProductAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter(FactorAdapter());
  await Hive.openBox<Product>(TableName.PRODUCT);
  await Hive.openBox<Factor>(TableName.FACTOR);
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Which one of your classes has typeId 32?

Comment: @Stijn2210 I don't have any thing with type id: 32